# Which Sun provider to use to generate an RSA key pair for encrypting (ciphering) data

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, jce, jca

I am trying to find out which of the Sun cryptographic providers should be used for generating an RSA key pair that will be used **encrypting** data in Java. I know that there are other providers such as Bouncy Castle, but I would like to use one of the Sun Providers. (algorithm: RSA, key size 2048)

For example, on my machine I currently have the following providers available:

- SUN 1.7
- SunRsaSign 1.7
- SunEC 1.7
- SunJSSE 1.7
- SunJCE 1.7
- SunJGSS 1.7
- SunSASL 1.7
- XMLDSig 1.0
- SunPCSC 1.7

I have previously used the provider SunRsaSign for generating an RSA key pair that was used for signing data. But I am not sure if it is safe or if it makes sense to use a key pair generated by SunRsaSign for encrypting data.

I have noticed that the provider SunJSSE contains: sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator

My main question is: which of the Sun providers should be used for generating an RSA key pair that will be used for **encryption** **(not signing)**?

Also, should a key pair generated by SunRsaSign only ever by used for signing data? Because the name of this provider contains the word "Sign" I assumed that it is specifically intended for signing, but now I am not so sure.

Finally, is it safe and does it makes sense to use a key pair generated by SunJSSE for general encryption? if so, what is the difference between an RSA generated by SunJSSE and an RSA key pair generated by SunJSSE?

Comment: Why even specify a provider? Normally you shouldn't concern yourself with the details of what the individual providers do. Hard-coding a specific provider makes you code less portable.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I totally understand your point, and in most cases I would agree with you. The reason I would like to specify the provider is because I am writing a library which assists (but also limits in some ways, for security reasons) client applications to access cryptographic services. Instead of permitting the provider with the highest priority in the list of providers to be used (how JCA works), I would like to only offer a reduced set of providers, which I have approved as being safe. I dont want to simply let the provider with the highest priority to be used, as it may be unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can have a look through all registered providers:

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider provider : providers) {
    Set<Service> services = provider.getServices();
    for (Service service : services) {
        service.getAlgorithm();
        // find algorithm and retrieve service information
    }
}
```

but in this case the solution would be simpler:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
Provider kpgenProv = kpgen.getProvider();
System.out.printf("Provider : %s%nInfo: %s%n", kpgenProv.getName(), kpgenProv.toString());
```

Result:

```
Provider : SunRsaSign
Info: SunRsaSign version 1.7
```

---

This is probably the only provider for your runtime that will generate RSA key pairs. Note that encryption is part of `javax.security`, which means that it was originally an optional package/provider (because of import/export control of cryptography).

RSA key creation is not encryption so it is included with `SunRsaSign` which provides RSA signature generation. As signatures are not used to provide confidentiality they are regarded as less sensitive cryptographic operations.

Comment: Thanks. But, part of my confusion comes from the fact that I dont know if it make sense to use the SunRsaSign provider to generate a key pair that will be used for encryption? As that provider name includes "Sign", I assumed that it was intended for generating key pairs that would be used for signing.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates that SunJCE does not provide RSA keys, which can be founded on SunRsaSign. Such that, using both are necessary, one to get the keys ans other to get the cipher.

from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider

The SunRsaSign Provider------------------------------------------------------------

KeyPairGenerator:

RSA 1024    Keysize must range between 512 and 65536 bits, the latter of which is unnecessarily large

The SunJCE Provider----------------------------------------------------------------

KeyPairGenerator

Diffie-Hellman (DH) 1024    Keysize must be a multiple of 64, ranging from 512 to 2048 (inclusive).

Comment: I have just got into the same problem, where specifying a provider was a requirement.